# How to send ldap searchquery with Scapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, ldap, scapy

I have a question related to the ldap protocol.

Is it possible to send a ldap / c-ldap searchquery using scapy?

Kind regards
Benshii

Answer (score 0):

Found It!

```
from scapy.all import *

def cldap_req():
    sr(IP(dst=ip)/UDP(sport=RandShort(), dport=389)/ldap)

ldap = b'\x30\x25\x02\x01\x01\x63\x20\x04\x00\x0a\x01'
ldap += b'\x00\x0a\x01\x00\x02\x01\x00\x02\x01\x00\x01\x01'
ldap += b'\x00\x87\x0b\x6f\x62\x6a\x65\x63\x74\x63\x6c\x61'
ldap += b'\x73\x73\x30\x00\x00'

cldap_req()
```